# Calculating the volume with triple integral

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals, volume, multiple-integral

Calculate the volume of $V$ limited by planes:
$$x+y=1, x+y=2, x=0, y=0, z=0, z=1$$

The projection on $xy$ is

[image: plot of the projection; WolframAlpha]

I tried finding the volume without integrals first:
$$V=Sh=\frac{1}{2}(2\cdot2-1\cdot1)\cdot (1-0)=\frac{3}{2}$$

And I got a completely different answer when calculating with integrals:
$$\int_{0}^{1}dz\int_{0}^{2}dx\int_{1-x}^{2-x}dy=\int_{0}^{1}dz\int_{0}^{2}dx(2-x-1+x)=\int_{0}^{1}dz\cdot2=2$$

Where did I go wrong?

Comment: What are $S$ and $h$?

Comment: $S$ is the surface of the base (just noticed it's usually $B$ in English) and $h$ is the height of the prism that we get.

Comment: By a direct comtutatuoon, you get  that $S=\frac12(\sqrt 2+2\sqrt 2)\times\sqrt 2=3$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you did using integrals is not correct. The part corresponding to $z$, yes, it is fine, but the part corresponding to $x$ and $y$ should be$$\int_0^1\int_{1-x}^{2-x}1\,\mathrm dy\,\mathrm dx+\int_1^2\int_0^{2-x}1\,\mathrm dy\,\mathrm dx=\frac32.$$

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: I'm glad I could help.